# Dynamically focus out blur contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rhnuE

I'm using JS Hotkeys from - https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

What I'm trying to do is deselect/focusout a focused contenteditable element. I also want the default focus dotted line to be removed when you click out of the element all called from the [Esc] key when pressed.

If anyone can help it'd be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Shortcut to deselect element
  $(document).bind('keydown', 'esc', function() {
    $('.box').focusout();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
    $('.box').blur()
```

instead of foucusout() it works fine for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) { // Key 27 is the same as Esc
    $('#formId').blur();
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: I got confused. I thought blur was for focus like live and delegate. I had to read up more on .blur from JQuery API's page. Thanks